# Flutter application: Required to terminate screen while navigating to next screen

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to terminate flutter screen without adding it to screen stack? Just like we do finish() in android?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? You want to go from Splash to Home screen and when back button pressed from Home, app should be closed or something else?

Comment: @dhuma1981 Yes exactly this is what i am trying to do. I am having 2 screens login screen and home screen. I am validating user login using REST API and storing response in shared preferences. When user opens app second time app should navigate to home screen instead of login screen.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pushReplacement or pushReplacementNamed.

1) With routes:
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/secondPage');

2) Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));

Comment: Worked!! Thanks @Ramziddin